# finding largest increasing subset of an array (non-contiguous)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How can I find the largest increasing (non-contiguous) subset of an array? For example, if A= array(50,1,4,9,2,18,6,3,7,10) the largest increasing non-contiguous subset is either (1,4,6,7,10) or (1,2,6,7,10). I can intuitively see how to find the subset, but I don't know how to design the algorithm.

Comment: Also see [Programming Pearls](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMP_en-USUS292&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=programming+pearls) for more homework clues and programming tips.

Comment: also - 1,9,18 has the same value as 1,4,6,7,10

Comment: and wouldn't 50 have the largest value?

Comment: He didn't say "largest value", merely "largest".  I think he's counting elements. Hence {50} = 1, {1,9,18} = 3, {1,4,6,7,10} = 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has pseudo-code for an efficient algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence_problem